# Adsense for web apps

Tags: adsense

Google has Adsense and Admob

- Adsense is thought for websites that have a lot of text and content (eg. blogs)
- Admob is for mobile apps

But what about web apps?

I have made several free-to-use web apps that are used daily because they help people do things (eg. convert something from one format to another) but they have no paragraphs and little text. Sometimes they are just a form input asking for a file and then the web app returns an output file.

**How can I put adsense in these web apps?**

I tried to apply for the Adsense program with my homepage but it got rejected. My homepage has a link to each of these web apps and a little description (eg. "A web app for converting XML to PDF", etc)

The rejection email says:

> We did not approve your application for the reasons listed below.
>
> Issues:
>
> Insufficient content:
>
> To be approved for AdSense and show
>   relevant ads on your site, your pages need to have enough text on them
>   for our specialists to review and for our crawler to be able to
>   determine what your pages are about.

So... as I see it: To be able to use adsense I will need to create a `.com` or `.net` (ie: a first level domain, as needed by Adsense) and fill it with "enough text" and "content".

But what content though? Should I invent content? **should I write about my cat?**

Writing is not my business. I do web apps.

Google thought on writers and provided Adsense for them.
Google also thought on mobile developers and provided Admob for them.

How should I proceed?

Comment: I have exact same questions! Did you get any solutions?

Comment: I suppose that if you do web apps, you just shouldn't use Admob. Maybe use some other ad network, or find a way of monetizing your project other than ads.

Comment: Web apps are websites so you need to add articles to let Google know your website it worth visiting.

Answer (score 0):

As you commented adsense requires you to publish "enough" content, this is quite subjective because it doesn't say how much is enough for them. I would recommend you to try [carbon](https://www.carbonads.net), I have used it to monetize my webapps and I have not had any problems.